# Alter a stream with trumpet, how to get content-length header in http.Response right?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a nodejs http server running and I want to alter content on specific sites (kind of my own private ad-blocker).
I decided to do this with [trumpet](https://github.com/substack/node-trumpet). Now the problem is, when trumpet injects the new content and pipes it to the http Response (http.IncomingMessage), the headers['content-length'] value is no more valid.

Some browsers do not seem to care (Chrome / Firefox on W7), others crash immediatly (Safari on iPad). I tried erasing the content-length header alltogether, with similar outcome (Safari waiting forever).

How can I set the content-length of the response right, after switching contents? I found [harmon](https://github.com/No9/harmon/#install), but I just need this last bit, so harmon felt like too much overhead. Or is it not that trivial?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know how big your response will be when you send the headers (the case here), you need to use [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Node should default to chunked transfer encoding if you do not specify any `Content-Length`.  Either remove the code that's setting the `Content-Length` header or try `res.removeHeader('Content-Length')`.

Comment: Nodejs is indeed chunking the responses, regardless of the property `content-length`.
Erasing the property lead to long loading times on Safari on iPad (for example), as stated in the initial question.
The last approach I had: Whenever there is content within a response, that I want to switch, I buffer the response, count the bytes, set the content-length and then write it to the request response. This is working, with the downside, that the request is no longer chunked (resulting in longer waiting time for the user until content shows). Is there a method without that downside?

Comment: Was trumpet's stream firing its `end` event?  If the response was indeed chunked and completed properly, you shouldn't see a long load time.